# Confidence interval containing $X_{(n+1)}$

Tags: confidence-interval

Sample size $n+1$, sample mean = $X_{bar}$ (size = n), sample deviation = $S$ (size=n)
How can we calculated confidence interval with 95% confidence, containing $X_{(n+1)}$ ?

If $E(X)=μ$, then $CI$ for $μ$ is $X_{bar} - t*S \sqrt n$, $X_{bar} + t*S\sqrt n$ as far as I think.
However, I don't know exact way to find $CI$ for $X_{(n+1)}...$

Comment: Please use MathJaX to typeset equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Such an interval is usually refered to as a prediction interval rather than a confidence interval. A derivation of the correct interval can be found at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval#Unknown_mean,_unknown_variance assuming that we are working with a normal distribution.